# Salam (Taslim) in Jamat Prayer

Tags: salat

What is the best way to perform taslim (salam) in Jamat prayer?
Do we need to say salam just after , when Imam says the first salam or do we need to wait until he says the second salam? Please give references in light of hadees and sunnah ...JazakAllah

Answer (score -3):

we need to say salam just after , when Imam says the first salam

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/69848/if-the-imam-says-the-salaam-and-the-person-praying-behind-him-has-not-finished-the-tashahhud-what-should-he-do